# childViewControllerForStatusBarHidden For Hiding

Tags: ios, statusbar, drawer

I am trying to hide half of my status bar. Specifically, I am using REFrostedViewController for my side drawer, and when it comes out, I would like it to go over the status such as in this picture (the app is Google's Inbox).

[image]

The current hierarchy of UIViewController as like so:

```
- REFrostedViewController
 |--MenuViewController
 |--NavigationControler
    |--ContentViewController
```

I have `UIViewControllerBasedStatusBarAppearance` set to `YES`. In my drawer menu (MenuViewController) I have the method

```
- (BOOL)prefersStatusBarHidden
{
    return YES;
}
```

In my Navigation Controller I have:

```
- (UIViewController *)childViewControllerForStatusBarHidden {
    return self.frostedViewController.menuViewController;
}
```

This hides the status bar in all screens. When I do

```
- (UIViewController *)childViewControllerForStatusBarHidden {
    if (self.isDrawerOpen) 
    {
        return self.frostedViewController.menuViewController;
    } else {
        return self.frostedViewController.contentViewController;
    }
}
```

It crashes. `self.frostedViewController.contentViewController` holds a navigationController (which also has the `prefersStatusBarHidden` method implemented)